# Mysql/adventureworks database/trigger question

Tags: mysql, adventureworks

Good afternoon I have been having some trouble trying to understand this question in class.The purpose of this assignment is to add parameters around data entry through triggers that are launched when specific conditions are met.

Due to warehousing limitations, inventory over 800 units needs to be sent to an external storage site and tracked separately. You have been asked to monitor when an update will exceed this boundary so it can be addressed in production meetings.
Write a trigger titled "tgrExcessInventory" for the Production.ProductInventory table to ensure the quantity can never exceed 800 units. This is step one. 
Modify the trigger created in step 1 to execute its check code only if the Quantity column is updated. I successfully created the trigger but I am having trouble understanding how to modify it? This is what I have so far. I Have seen a few other post on here similar to this question, but I haven't seen any with the modification done to it. I feel it'something small im missing. From my understanding I need to write an alter statement?

```
CREATE TRIGGER tgrExcessInventory
on Production.ProductInventory
FOR UPDATE
AS
IF EXISTS
    (SELECT 'True'
    FROM Inserted i
    JOIN Deleted d
            ON i.productID = d.ProductID
            AND i.locationID = d.LocationID
            WHERE (d.quantity + i.quantity) >= 800 OR 
            i.quantity >=800

    )Begin
    RAISERROR('Cant increase supply where units would be over 800 
    units',16,1)
            ROLLBACK TRAN
    END
```

Then I did the alter function

```
      ALTER TRIGGER [Production].[tgrExcessInventory]
      on [Production].[ProductInventory]
      FOR UPDATE
      AS
      IF EXISTS
      (SELECT 'True'
      FROM Inserted I
       JOIN Deleted D
            ON i.Quantity = d.quantity
            AND i.Quantity = d.Quantity
            WHERE (d.quantity + i.quantity) >= 800 OR 
            i.quantity >=800

    )Begin
    RAISERROR('Cant increase supply where units would be over 800 units',16,1)
            ROLLBACK TRAN
    END
```

Seems to work? I believe i did this right any tips would be appreciated thanks for your time

Comment: "Modify the trigger created in step 1" - What the step 1 ? What was the final trigger code in step 1 ? Please add all these details to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you read here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/193219/alter-procedure-in-mysql

regarding `ALTER PROCEDURE`

> This statement can be used to change the characteristics of a stored procedure. More than one change may be specified in an `ALTER PROCEDURE` statement. However, you **cannot change the** parameters or **body** **of a stored procedure** using this statement; to make such changes, you **must drop and re-create the procedure** using `DROP PROCEDURE` and `CREATE PROCEDURE`.

You can easily alter a procedure using an alter statement if it is a minor change. If you want to make bigger changes, you should use `SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE tgrExcessInventory` then make your changes, drop the existing procedure `DROP PROCEDURE IF EXIST tgrExcessInventory`  and run the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement  with your changes